# How to parse soap+xml message that is passed into my wcf service operation?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have the following Soap Request I receive from the client, where basically I have to extract the Name and then send back "Hello Test"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Customer>
    <ns1:Name>Test</ns1:Name>
    </ns1:Customer>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I have a class Customer define like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I am unsure how to pass in the soap request to my wcf service operation which will take in a Customer Request Object generated from an xsd?

After my wcf service operation receives the soap request, I am not sure how to get the Name attribute out of it and send a response back to the client, like maybe "Hello Test"

Note:  The client is not going to send a Customer object, they are going to send an xml request and I have to parse it into a Customer object.  I hope this clears things up.

Do I have to do something like this where I pass in a XDocument to my wcf service operation:

```
private static void ParsSoapDocument(XDocument soapDocument)
{
   //Parse XDocument for elements/attributes

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have to parse anything, this is what WCF handles for you.

There may be variations based on whether you are using wrapped/unwrapped messages, but the basic scenario, for the soap message you describe coming from the client, your service interface would be as follows (assuming your response is a `string`):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public string Customer(string Name);
}
```

More likely, you are actually trying to perform an operation which takes in a Customer. For instance, to check if a customer exists you might have:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public bool CheckCustomerExists(Customer Customer);
}
```

and your `Customer` class on the service side would need to be defined as a `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

This would make the soap request look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"> <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CheckCustomerExists>
    <ns1:Customer>
    <ns1:Name>Test</ns1:Name>
    </ns1:Customer>
    </ns1:CheckCustomerExists> </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Ethan, Thanks for this.   I have clients send me requests, so I don't control the request, I just control what I do when I get the request, like adding a customer to a database.  Do you know how I can view the soap request/response in .net (e.g. - with Console.WriteLine(...))

Comment: @john I mention using `MessageContract` in two places, so not exactly sure which one you are asking about. First, I mentioned that you would need to use `MessageContract` if the operation took a Customer object as opposed to a simple datatype. I suppose you could also use `DataContract` but I typically use messages (which gets to the second `MessageContract` reference). Second, I suggest using Request/Response if the op has control over design of the message and if the messages are going to be fairly complex.

Comment: @Xaisoft - For viewing the SOAP being sent across the wire, you can use Fiddler. You can also call a service using SoapUI which will show you the raw response. These are both good (and free) tools to add to your arsenal. There is also logging capability which can be turned on/off easily through the WCF Service Configuration Editor, but the output can be a little difficult to work with if you are a beginner (or an expert...)

Comment: @Ethan: `MessageContract` is only necessary if you have multiple body and/or header parts. Otherwise, `DataContract` is what should be used.

Comment: @John - you are right. `DataContract` is all that is needed. As for my closing comment, I still advocate a message based approach if the service operations grow complex, but the Messages can be defined using `DataContract` unless greater control over the SOAP Structure is needed (promoting fields to the header for instance). I still think -1 is a little harsh though considering I answered the ops question :) Teaches me to add on extra information.

Comment: @Ethan: I tend to vote harshly. Readers actually _listen_ to us. I was concerned that the OP would begin using `MessageContract` for all of his WCF development, for no good reason. Downvote removed.